# Calculate the circumference of an irregular shape

Tags: add-on, bezier-curves, physics, geometry

I watched your video "100+ Tips to Boost Modeling in Blender", it's great, I couldn't pick it up.
I am involved in a humanitarian association. I am an ortho-prosthetist and I make 3D prostheses for children in West Africa.
I have to model the stumps that I scan. I need to know the circumference of an irregular surface, like a leg.

Is there an add-on that allows it?
Thanks in advance for the information.
Roberto

[image]
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by circumference? do you want a radius for the circumscribed circle of a section, or the real perimeter of that section?

Comment: Hello! This is the perimeter, the turn of the leg.